# How to find the data type of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have imported email module for my code, and there is a question for which I am not able to find any proper answer for. everything works fine and the result is what I am looking for. But I am curious to know what is happening under the hood.

The function is as below:

```
email.message_from_string(email_string)
```

I want to know the data type of the output of the above function. so what I did, is:

```
print(type(email.message_from_string('email_file')))
<class 'email.message.Message'>
```

It returns the result as email class.
I have assigned the above function to a variable as below, and again the same response as above.

```
email_message= email.message_from_string('email_file')
<class 'email.message.Message'>
```

But when I hover my mouse, in my editor(Pycharm|VSCode), on the variable it shows the "email_message" data type is 'dict'.
[image]

I'm completely confused and I do not know where the problem comes from.

Comment: it could inherit the dict type, check it with isinstance(object, dict)

Comment: It's totally fine for a function to return a class instance. In this case, you will get an instance of the `email.message.Message` class which is described here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html. It inherits from dict, so this is what pycharm shows you.

Comment: @Dschoni- but the output data type is 'dict' as the editor shows.

Comment: @frab- result is False.

Comment: So, the answer to your question is the return type of `email.message_from_string` is an instance of `class email.message.Message`. And that's it. It's a totally different question why pycharm chooses to show you a dict. In my IDE (Spyder) it shows correctly as `message.Message` type.

Comment: BTW, sorry for my above remark. Indeed it does NOT inherit from dict (at least I didn't find any obvious inheritance in the source). It re-implements the `keys` and `values` attributes of `dict` though.

Comment: @Dschoni, Thanks for your prompt response. would you please explain more about your last sentence. I didn't get completely what you meant. since this function is getting keys and values.

Comment: Have a look at the implementation. You should be able to find it `lib\email` in the folder of your python installation. `message.Message` implements class methods `keys` and `values` so that the interface of `message.Message` becomes compatible with `dict`.